# ASP.NET Core 6 The view 'Login' was not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core 6 application is running well in the development environment, but when I publish the project this error is shown:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[3]
      The view 'Login' was not found. Searched locations: /Views/Account/Login.cshtml, /Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Login' was not found. The following locations were searched:
      /Views/Account/Login.cshtml
      /Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable`1 originalLocations)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Hatch.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtTokenMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<UseJwtTokenMiddleware>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Shirani\Documents\Projects\Frame.Hatch\src\Hatch.Web.Core\Authentication\JwtBearer\JwtTokenMiddleware.cs:line 22
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.ResponseCachingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

Comment: Have you cross check into your publish folder that *Login.cshtml* is there?

Comment: In ASP.NET Core there is no Views folder and it's all in a dll file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when I publish with CLI like this:

```
dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile
```

the published files work fine. But the published files produced by Visual Studio 2022 have the above error.